# Javascript Conflicts in Console for Wordpress Plugin Global Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I hope you can help me to debug my conflicts on the site I am working on:

URL: http://metalotechnika.com
PW: 12345678

If you then go to http://metalotechnika.com/foto-galeri/foto-kangjella-hekuri/

You will find a gallery that isn't loading. Most probably due to javascript conflicts. Could you pint me in the right direction here?

You will find some errors in the console: "TypeError: jQuery(...).lcweb_lazyload is not a function"

I thougt, that it must be jQuery not loading correctly. But I already tested jQuery in my main.js, and is working. Don't know about this time.

Comment: jQuery is loaded. `lcweb_lazyload` what is not a function. It's not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem.

jQuery is loaded 2 times. And this is were the conflict came from. I just removed jQuery from my functions.php because Wordpress already loads it's own jQuery and throws conflicts if it is loaded a separate different time.

Thanks anyway.